# How to find out the TabSelection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have using the following code for developing tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container-1').tabs();
}
 ....
<div id="container-1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

...
```

It works fine! I need the tab click event. If it is the *Home* tab click, I have to do `alert();`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd handle it all in the tab configuration itself rather than adding click events to the elements which ultimately will be the clickable part of the tab.  If you do it via the tab config, then all of your tab logic is centralized thus making things cleaner and you don't need to be familiar with the implementation details of the tabs:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#container-1').tabs({
          selected : function(e, ui) {
            if (ui.index == 0) {
                alert('Home clicked!');
            }
          }        
      }); 
  });
   ....
  <div  id="container-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Contact</span></a></li>

         </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes , I tried with your solution Not working I have included all necessary latest jquery plugin.any samples i welcom

Comment: I use this in my tabbed pages and I whipped up a test before I posted, that being said I noticed the ending ); was missing from the actual example given (my apologies: fixed).  Give that a go and we'll take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

Set the id of the *Home* tab span element:

```
<li><a href="#fragment-1"><span id="home">Home</span></a></li>
```

And add the click handler to it somewhere:

```
$("#home").click(function()
{
    alert("Home tab is selected!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the tab click event, you would do something like one of the following.

```
$("#tabid").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do tab click logic
});
```

or

```
$(".tabclass").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do tab click logic
});
```

Do a search for [jQuery cheat sheet](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=jquery+cheatsheet&meta=&btnG=Google+Search) to get yourself a very useful jQuery cheat sheet.